# Converting eclipse java project to maven doesn't create src/test/java directory

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I successfully converted an eclipse (Luna 4.4) Java project to Maven. To use JUnit, I added that as a maven dependency. Here is my resulting project structure as seen in eclipse:

[image]

I was expecting that adding JUnit would also create the `src/test/Java` source folder to hold my JUnit source code, but it's not there. Is this expected? Does one have to manually add these folders after a conversion from a Java project? I saw that when I created a new Maven project in eclipse and added the very same JUnit dependency, the test folder gets created automatically.

Comment: What's the problem with creating the folder manually? Afer it's created you just go to project's configuration and add the folder to Build Path.

Comment: BTW, your source folder isn't `src/main/java` as it is recommended by [Maven's Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Answer (score 4):

The creation of test folder happens when you create a new maven project, it is not when you add the jUnit dependency. This is part of the "mvn archetype:generate" command.

So in your case, i would suggest you create a new maven project and copy the /src/ folder manually

Comment: Creating _"a new maven project and"_ (Eclipse-)importing _"[his] existing java project"_ leads to two projects independent of each other, not to one Maven project containing his code, doesn't it?

Comment: @GeroldBroser Yes you are right, here "and" shouldn't be there. I meant to create a maven project and copy the src folder. The wordings have been updated to reflect it

Comment: The first part is correct now. Thanks for updating your answer. The last sentence still isn't: In Eclipse Luna (and in all previous versions, AFAIR) there are imports for _Existing Projects into Workspace_ and _Existing Maven Projects_. There is not (and has never been) an import for _Import existing (Java) Project as Maven Project_. So, the most practical solution is the one with: _Creating a new Maven project_ → _Copying the `src` folder's content to `src/main/java`_ → _Importing as Existing Maven Project into Eclipse._